# Possible to open/read an .md/.html file automatically in my main HTML for blog site?

Tags: html, markdown, blogs

I'm trying to create a blog using HTML/CSS. So far, I've created and styled the page and I want to start adding blog posts.

Instead of filling up my HTML document with the blog article in a `<p>` or `<h*something*>` tag, I was hoping I can link to a local `.md` file in a blog-articles folder. That way, I can write the blogs in as .md files, stash them in the folder, and link them into my website.

Is this possible?

**edit**

I'd basically like to replace the typed out blog post in the main HTML with a link to either a `.md` or `.html` file that opens/reads automatically.

https://codepen.io/kremebey/pen/RJdQJp

[I've commented out the part of the HTML where the adjustment would likely occur]

Comment: This describes the functioning of many static site generators. Take a look at [StaticGen](https://www.staticgen.com/) for the most popular. They all offer simple ways to write your posts and customizable templates, both of which they combine in a single step to create a website that’s simple HTML. No database needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js which is a great markdown visualizer. Or you could convert it to HTML with this: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_markdown_syntax_color.html Hope this helps!